# Storing Data within a Restaurant Item

Tags: java, android

So I have a custom list of restaurants. When the restaurant is clicked I want a set of data coming up (Name, phone number, rating, category) and I want the user to be able to modify that data and for that data to remain the same when left from that screen. Is there any way to store the data for each restaurant? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "is there any way to store the data for each restaurant?" -- that's exactly what your Restaurant object is doing. If you're talking about persistent storage, then you have databases, flat files, and many more options at your disposal, but you need to be specific about what you're really trying to do and what your requirements are. As it stands, this is not a well-worded question.

Comment: Currently each Restaurant is in a list array. I want to be able to have the ability to add a restaurant object with data of the name, phone number, rating and category. I also want the user to be able to modify the data if they choose @MarsAtomic

Comment: You mean an ArrayList? Fine. That will meet your stated needs, but a big part of design is choosing the right data structures, so you need to know the alternatives, what they can do and how you can use them. This knowledge is going to determine how you design your application. If you don't know what a Map is and how to use it, now would be a good time to research. Honestly, it sounds like you're getting ahead of yourself, and you need to spend more time reading and less time coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user changes to only be preserved in his device only then using a database is the best option. I highly recommend going with [Room Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

1. First of all, you should define your restaurant model as an entity for room;
2. define a Dao object to create, list and edit your entities;
3. define an abstract class as the database. Room will provide the implementation at compile time itself;
4. access and manipulate database items using dao object in database implementation.

For details on the steps mentioned [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) is the best place to start.